# How to add manually customised seaborn plots to JointGrid/jointplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, jointplot

I want to use the seaborn JointGrid/jointplot.

In the middle I would like to add a sns.regplot. On the Margins two sns.distplots or histograms.

Thats not a problem, but I would like to custmize all three pplots differently and add different fiiting functions and labels to all three of them.

But I cant solve the problem, how to get the instances of the plots if i just use the predifined method:

```
g = sns.JointGrid(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips)
g = g.plot(sns.regplot, sns.distplot)
```

to manually manipulated those.
Or the other way around to create one regplot and two distplot instances, which I define the way I wnat and then add them to the JointGrid, something in the meaning of, but unfortinaltely, these below methods don't exist or don't work that way:

```
g = sns.JointGrid(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips)
g.add_joint(myreg)           # That would be great but doesn't work
g.ax_marg_x.add(mydist1)     # Just invented code
g.ax_marg_y.add(mydist2)     # Just to show you, the way I'd like to solve the issue
```

Can you give me an advice, how to get around this issue?

Comment: I don't think I understand...Isn't the second code sample the answer to your question?

Comment: Thx, mwaskom, for your response. Yes that would be the answer, but unfortunately, these methods don't exist or don't work that way...

Comment: `ax_marg_x` and `ax_marg_y` are just the actual matplotlib Axes objects, so you could call any method on them (e.g. `ax.hist()`) or pass them to the `ax=` parameter of a seaborn function like `distplot`.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. But unfortunately either it doesn't work or i didn't get what u tried me to do.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. But unfortunately either it doesn't work or i didn't get what u tried me to do. `myPlot = sns.JointGrid(x="volume_x", y="volume_y", data=c); myPlot.plot_joint(plt.scatter); myPlot.ax_marg_x = plt.hist(c["volume_x"]); myPlot.ax_marg_y = plt.hist(c["volume_y"], orientation="horizontal")` all the single plots work fine if I just print them for themself, but if I add the histograms directly to the marginal axes using `=` nothing is shown on the grid. Can you perhaps write out the lines you wanted me to test? Thanks again for your great help!

Answer (score 1):

Well, the [documentation has a few examples](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.JointGrid.html#seaborn.JointGrid). If you want the same `distPlot` on both marginals:

```
g = sns.JointGrid(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips)
g = g.plot_joint(plt.scatter, color=".5", edgecolor="white")
g = g.plot_marginals(sns.distplot, kde=True, color=".5")
```

Or if you want a different plot on each marginal

```
g = sns.JointGrid(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips)
g = g.plot_joint(sns.regplot, color="m")
_ = g.ax_marg_x.hist(tips["total_bill"], color="b", alpha=.6,
                     bins=np.arange(0, 60, 5))
_ = g.ax_marg_y.hist(tips["tip"], color="r", alpha=.6,
                     orientation="horizontal",
                     bins=np.arange(0, 12, 1))
```

And then it took 2 seconds of experimenting to make sure you could pass your own custom plot functions to both the marginals and jointPlot, and had to set a breakpoint to figure out what parameter determined the orientation of the marginal plot

```
def customJoint(x,y,*args,**kwargs):
    plt.scatter(x,y,color='red')
def customMarginal(x,*args,**kwargs):
    sns.distplot(x,color='green', vertical=kwargs['vertical'])

g = sns.JointGrid(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips)
g = g.plot(customJoint, customMarginal)
```